ImportError в Python
Есть приложение на fastapi. Перенёс основной функционал приложения в папку books, и в случае импорта в main.py возникает ImportError.
Вот мой код:
from books import books_router
from fastapi import FastAPI
from auth import auth_router
from redis import asyncio as aioredis
from fastapi_cache import FastAPICache
from fastapi_cache.backendsвведите сюда код`.redis import RedisBackend

app = FastAPI()

app.include_router(auth_router.router, prefix="/auth", tags=["auth"])
app.include_router(books_router.router, prefix="/books", tags=["books"])

@app.on_event("startup")
async def startup_event():
    redis = aioredis.from_url("redis://localhost", encoding="utf8", decode_responses=True)
    FastAPICache.init(RedisBackend(redis), prefix="fastapi-cache")

Вот ошибка:
File "f:\programming\simpleCRUDInFastAPI\app\main.py", line 1, in <module>
    from books import books_router

И структура проекта:


попробуй абсолютный путь к файлу

не помогло только ошибка поменялась на \main.py", line 1, in 
from app.books import books_router

Если вы хотите, чтобы app был модулем (судя по наличию файла __init__.py в нём), то тогда и запускайте его содержимое как модуль python -m app.main

а если вообще говорить, то самый мега простой и деревянный способ - это перенести всё в одну папку

"Вот ошибка:" - это не ошибка, это ее стэктрейс, нужен полный текст ошибки.
